# Implementing Mutex in windows phone Mango

Tags: windows-phone-7

How we can implement mutex in windows phone mango, Is that restricted to use with Scheduled task? I searched for online tutorials, but didn't get any gud ones. Please any one help me to learn this topic. or suggest me some nice links to learn the topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use a [Monitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) instead, but as you can see here: [Mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) - there is allready a Mutex in WP7 ;)

Comment: add some samples, that may help us to understand the technique easily

Comment: well without some codesample to work with it wouldn't be any different from the samples you can find easily online at MSDN - for example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4tssbxcw%28v=VS.95%29.aspx - it's just not all to different from the stuff you use elswhere in .net - you just have to check of special classes are included in WP7 (yet)